# Concatenated i18n string with variable in HAML

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, haml

This is my code

```
%ul.thumbnails
  %li.span3
    %header
      %h2
        = link_to t('homepage.house.link'), houses_path
```

I have a variable @country.name. How can I add/concatenate this variable to t('homepage.house.link')?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure how `t()` works. What about:

```
= link_to t("homepage.house.link" + @country.name), houses_path
```

If you just want the link name change you can do:

```
= link_to t("homepage.house.link") + @country.name, houses_path
```

Or string interpolate the entire line:

```
= link_to "#{t('homepage.house.link')} #{@country.name}", houses_path
```

Comment: yep...by example the value of @country.name is "italy" and the value from homepage.house.link is "holiday homes in" Now i that the link is "holiday homes in Italy" Any ideas?

Comment: thanks..i tried your idea but it show only the value of country and not the value of homepage.house.link